# C# Regular Expression: How to extract a collection

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have collection in text file:

```
(Collection
  (Item "Name1" 1 2 3)
  (Item "Simple name2" 1 2 3)
  (Item "Just name 3" 4 5 6))
```

Collection also could be empty:

```
(Collection)
```

The number of items is undefined. It could be one item or one hundred. By previous extraction I already have inner text between Collection element:

```
(Item "Name1" 1 2 3)(Item "Simple name2" 1 2 3)(Item "Just name 3" 4 5 6)
```

In the case of empty collection it will be empty string.

**How could I parse this collection using .Net Regular Expression?**

I tried this:

```
string pattern = @"(\(Item\s""(?<Name>.*)""\s(?<Type>.*)\s(?<Length>.*)\s(?<Number>.*))*";
```

But the code above doesn't produce any real results.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use regex differently:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(document, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups["Name"].Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Name"].Captures[i].Value);
    }
}
```

or

```
while (m.Success)
{
    m.Groups["Name"].Value.Dump();
    m.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: @Michele Virgilio: In output I want extract all Items, e.g. names, types, lengths and numbers

Comment: So you need to parse only (Item "Name1" 1 2 3)(Item "Simple name2" 1 2 3)(Item "Just name 3" 4 5 6)
not the entire string

Comment: I think that would be better to leave the multiline parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\(Item (?<part1>\".*?\")\s(?<part2>\d+)\s(?<part3>\d+)\s(?<part4>\d+)\)
```

this will create a collection of matches:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(
      "\\(Item (?<part1>\\\".*?\\\")\\s(?<part2>\\d+)\\s(?<part3>\\d"+
      "+)\\s(?<part4>\\d+)\\)",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );

//Capture all Matches in the InputText
MatchCollection ms = regex.Matches(InputText);


//Get the names of all the named and numbered capture groups
string[] GroupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();

// Get the numbers of all the named and numbered capture groups
int[] GroupNumbers = regex.GetGroupNumbers();
```

Comment: I have no idea whether this will work or not but always using a minimal capture (eg \d+ is always better than a massive greedy match like .* since this will happily match all your delimiters and anything else given half a chance. I'd even like to see the first .* be replaced with something more specific though we don't know what is valid in there currently.

Comment: Infact the greedy match is used only between " delimiters, which can contain any text.

Comment: The problem is that the greedy match will match those delimiters given half a chance. When you have two items for example it will match `Name1" 1 2 3)(Item "Simple name2" 1 2 3)(Item "Just name 3`. Using [^"]* would be better than .* to prevent it matching your delimiter. Of course there may be some escaping mechanism for quotes inside the quotes in which case this would fail for other reasons...

Comment: Yes, but that would not work in this case:
(Item "Name1" 1 2 3)
(Item "Simple \" name2" 1 2 3)
(Item "Just name 3" 4 5 6)
the item 2 would be not matched at all

Comment: Well quite which is what my last sentence said. The input string is currently not fully specified for this reason. Using a non-greedy match (.*?) should probably work though since it will chomp the \" in order to make the rest of the pattern match. I'd just prefer it if we knew that the name was always alphanumeric and spaces or something like that rather than having to try to worry about escaped quotes and such like for exactly the same reason as you are using \d+ instead of just .+

Comment: @Chris: Name is: list of any character except LineFeed (&h0A), "{", or """ (also it might be empty)

Comment: so use \(Item (?<part1>\"[^\n{\"]*?\")\s(?<part2>\d+)\s(?<part3>\d+)\s(?<part4>\d+)\)

Comment: @Michele Virgilio: It works but it lost one item from four. Update: yes it works for all items.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to make your captures non-greedy...

```
(?<Name>.*?)
```

instead of

```
(?<Name>.*)
```

Comment: In this case only first item is captured

Comment: @JohnKZ: How are you using the regex? The whole point of making it non-greedy is to make it match only one item rather than assuming that the name for the first one is `Name1" 1 2 3)(Item "Simple name2" 1 2 3)(Item "Just name 3` or something equally broken.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read file and than make use of Sting.Split function to split the collection and start to read it

```
   String s = "(Collection
              (Item "Name1" 1 2 3)
              (Item "Simple name2" 1 2 3)
              (Item "Just name 3" 4 5 6))";

   string colection[] = s.Split('(');
   if(colection.Length>1)
   {
      for(i=1;i<colection.Length;i++)
      {
          //process string one by one and add ( if you need it
          //from the last item remove )
      }
   }
```

this will resolve issue easily there is no need of put extra burden of regulat expression.

Comment: I agree with this. I assume when you are getting your string of just items you must be doing something similar to the above already. At that stage I'd just parse each item rather than putting it into a string for regex. If nothing else regexing over a smaller string makes life much easier. :)

Comment: This will fail horribly if he has a parenthesis inside one of those strings.

Comment: @Ilia Jerebtsov - code is generated based on the sting given by op..i agree it will fail if there is ( occur in the string